# I am not getting the below header files in c language

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h> //Unable to find all of this header files
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <ctype.h>          
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
```

I want to use this header files ion my program and i cannot find it on the internet please provide a source from which i could get them

Comment: your computer? Maybe you need to reinstall C?

Comment: Looks like a unix system the code snippet assumes. You just might not find it if you are not on a unix system...

Comment: Did you configure the directories in the program? Generally you might need to configure them.

Comment: Which platform are you running on? Which compiler do you use? How do you compile the code (what flags)?

Comment: I have no idea about all this if you know then please guide

Comment: Okay - step by step: Do you sit at a windows pc or a linux or a mac or a freebsd?

Comment: There we go: On windows you have different header files: winsock.h, winsock2.h ...

Comment: ok so from where could i get them?

Comment: if you installed visual studio or if you installed windows sdk you have them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254447/file-transfer-server-client-using-socket(I want to implement this program) so please guide accordingly

Comment: That question assumes a unix system. It looks a bit different on windows. C is portable but this does not mean you get all apis in the same way on every system.

Comment: ok so if i want to build a similar program in windows that how can i do it

Answer (score 0):

On windows, socket api is packed into a different set of headers. But the way the windows sockets work (if used in a "portable" way) is pretty much the same as on unix systems. Give or take.

The example code from the other question you linked looks like this on windows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
//#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
//#include <sys/wait.h>
//#include <sys/socket.h>
//#include <signal.h>
#include <ctype.h>          
//#include <arpa/inet.h>
//#include <netdb.h>

#define PORT 20000
#define LENGTH 512 


void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Variable Definition */
    SOCKET sockfd;
    char revbuf[LENGTH];
    struct sockaddr_in remote_addr;

    /* Get the Socket file descriptor */
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed to obtain Socket Descriptor! (errno = %d)\n", errno);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Fill the socket address struct */
    remote_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    remote_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &remote_addr.sin_addr);
    ZeroMemory(&(remote_addr.sin_zero), 8);

    /* Try to connect the remote */
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed to connect to the host! (errno = %d)\n", errno);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("[Client] Connected to server at port %d...ok!\n", PORT);

    /* Send File to Server */
    //if(!fork())
    //{
    char* fs_name = "/home/aryan/Desktop/quotidiani.txt";
    char sdbuf[LENGTH];
    printf("[Client] Sending %s to the Server... ", fs_name);
    FILE *fs = NULL;
    errno_t err = fopen_s(&fs, fs_name, "r");
    if (fs == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: File %s not found.\n", fs_name);
        exit(1);
    }

    ZeroMemory(sdbuf, LENGTH);
    int fs_block_sz;
    while ((fs_block_sz = fread(sdbuf, sizeof(char), LENGTH, fs)) > 0)
    {
        if (send(sockfd, sdbuf, fs_block_sz, 0) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed to send file %s. (errno = %d)\n", fs_name, errno);
            break;
        }
        ZeroMemory(sdbuf, LENGTH);
    }
    printf("Ok File %s from Client was Sent!\n", fs_name);
    //}

    /* Receive File from Server */
    printf("[Client] Receiveing file from Server and saving it as final.txt...");
    char* fr_name = "/home/aryan/Desktop/progetto/final.txt";
    FILE *fr = NULL;
    err = fopen_s(&fr, fr_name, "a");
    if (fr == NULL)
        printf("File %s Cannot be opened.\n", fr_name);
    else
    {
        ZeroMemory(revbuf, LENGTH);
        int fr_block_sz = 0;
        while ((fr_block_sz = recv(sockfd, revbuf, LENGTH, 0)) > 0)
        {
            int write_sz = fwrite(revbuf, sizeof(char), fr_block_sz, fr);
            if (write_sz < fr_block_sz)
            {
                error("File write failed.\n");
            }
            ZeroMemory(revbuf, LENGTH);
            if (fr_block_sz == 0 || fr_block_sz != 512)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (fr_block_sz < 0)
        {
            if (errno == EAGAIN)
            {
                printf("recv() timed out.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "recv() failed due to errno = %d\n", errno);
            }
        }
        printf("Ok received from server!\n");
        fclose(fr);
    }
    //close(sockfd);
    closesocket(sockfd);
    printf("[Client] Connection lost.\n");
    return (0);
}
```

Now you can compare and see what is the same and what is a bit different. Hope that helps you to understand.

In case, you wonder next, why you have linker errors: Link against `ws2_32.lib`. In contrast to unix systems, where sockets are part of "libc", sockets are factored out into a separate dll in windows.